# How to install laravel on windows, if my wamp is not installed on c drive?

Tags: laravel, terminal

i have a problem while installing laravel through composer using cmd on windows. wherein my wamp is installed on d drive. before this, I did this with same method describe on laravel documentation. where, my wamp installation on default c drive.
I'm new to this terminal and command line interface. don't have much clarification. need more solution on this thank you in advance.

I'm stuck here, do I need to installed wamp again on c drive?

Comment: CD into the htdocs folder and run the create-project command relative to your current directory.

Comment: What steps do you stuck in?

Comment: As mentioned whats stopping you from opening the wamp folder on the other drive and running the laravel create project .... so in the terminal cd into the root wamp folder where your sites are and run the installer, then set up your local host file to point to your newly created project then view in browser. post any errors as well

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got the answer, i wanted to know how to go to D directory using command propmt. i got answered and i have installed laravel on it. just typing **d:**